# How to setup a Docker container to use pre-existing (secondary) network with fixed MAC address?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Using Docker Compose below, I setup a Docker stack that has one **front-end** container and one **back-end** container. By default, they both utilize internal network bridge to communicate with one and another. To access the front-end container externally, I connected the **front-end** container to a second network which will be assigned a random IP address by the external router using a special Docker networking plugin called [docker-net-dhcp](https://github.com/devplayer0/docker-net-dhcp).

```
front-end:
  image: gdeflaux/restyaboard-ldap
  links:
    - back-end
  volumes:
    - /volume/path/config:/etc/restyaboard
    - /volume/path/media:/var/nginx/html/media
back-end:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=restyaboard
```

The problem is that every time that the **front-end** container gets restarted the network port connected to the second network gets a different MAC address. Because of that, I can't fixed a particular MAC address to a particular IP address on the router end.

Therefore, it leads me to the question - how to setup a Docker container to use a pre-existing secondary network with fixed MAC address?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external-1

Comment: I have looked through that documentation before. I can't find anything in regard to setting up MAC address.

Comment: There is a [mac_address](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) setting right there in the docs. But, I don't think you need that! That's why the first link points you to the documentation about the `external` directive for networks.

Comment: Actually, I do need that. After some more digging and some trial and error, what I am trying to get is currently impossible to do based on this [link](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5261). In summary, I can only define a MAC address for first network. I can't do that for other network from Docker Compose side. Let me see if I can solve this problem after the Docker stack is created, because I can join the front-end container to a second network afterward.

Comment: Nothing you've described in your question requires a fixed MAC address. A fixed ip address, maybe, although I suspect even that's unnecessary if you can get a fixed hostname that points at your target container.

Comment: Using a fixed IP address is not allowed when I configured it via Docker CLI. It complains that I can only do that for "user configured subnets". Using a hostname might work if I can get Nginx server to be able to resolve the hostname to a dynamic IP address, but it is another possible workaround, not a solution.

Comment: To collaborate further on why I need a fixed MAC address, my external router is setup to map certain MAC addresses to certain IP addresses while dynamic assigning IP addresses for other non-server devices. This configuration allows me to easily setup my Nginx server to properly reverse-proxy to the correct servers by its IP address. This won't work for containers since I can only use the IP address of the docker host, so I utilized the docker-net-dhcp for this purpose. I can assign certain containers to have its own external IP address as if it is an own independent server when it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further digging, this is currently impossible to assign a fixed MAC address for a second network, which is what I was trying to achieve. Assigning a MAC address to a container will only get applied to only one network and that network, by default, will always be the internal bridge network. See this [link](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5261) for more details and explanations.

There are two workarounds to this. One is to create the Docker Stack from Docker Compose file first and then connect the container to the external network via the CLI with **docker network connect --ip="192.168.x.x" NETWORK CONTAINER** command. This will only work if you are using an user configured subnets, which, in my case, will not work using docker-net-dhcp.

The second workarounds is to wait for the feature of **Network priority** to be implemented. See this [link](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1372) for more information.